Sundance Flick about revenge killings
About 10-15 years ago, I saw a Sundance film whose violence was so traumatic/realistic, I still shudder when I think about it today. For some reason, no other movie has ever had such an effect on me like this movie has. I doubt it was very popular -- it seemed very low budget, but good acting, and again seemed very "realistic" in every way. Very, very disturbing.
Anyway, it's basically portrays a man's revenge killings. he fell for a younger, awkwardly shy woman at his workplace (some type of warehouse job). he befriends her during ongoing smoke breaks. Other coworkers get drunk/high one night with her, and accidentally kill her. After she dies in the car they use to take her to the hospital, they decide to cover up their crime by dismembering her; her head was hidden in one of the accidental killers basement. But, our "hero" finds out about the crime, and obtains more details by terrorizing one of the suspects and his family into submission. He then single-handedly stalks each one of the other killers and kills all of them in very violent/realistic ways.
By the way, I think the title has something to do with the fourth of july or something similar, but I may be completely off. I do remember the title didn't seem to have anything at all to do with the actual events in the movie.

By "Sundance flick" you mean a movie that screened at the Sundance Film Festival or do you mean a movie that aired on the Sundance TV channel?

sorry -- I meant a movie that appeared on the Sundance channel.
